# How to apply argrelextrema function in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am tryig to apply argrelextrema function with dataframe df. But unable to apply correctly. below is my code

```
    import pandas as pd
    from scipy.signal import argrelextrema 
    np.random.seed(42)

        def maxloc(data):
            loc_opt_ind = argrelextrema(df.values, np.greater)
            loc_max = np.zeros(len(data))
            loc_max[loc_opt_ind] = 1
            data['loc_max'] = loc_max
            return data

        values = np.random.rand(23000)
        df = pd.DataFrame({'value': values})
        np.all(maxloc_faster(df).loc_max)

It gives me error 
that loc_max[loc_opt_ind] = 1
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Pandas dataframe is two-dimensional. That is, `df.values` is two dimensional, *even* when it has only one column. As a result, `loc_opt_ind` will contain x and y indices (two tuples; just print `loc_opt_ind` to see), which can't be used to index `loc_max`. You probably want to use either `df['values'].values` (which turns into `<Series>.values`), or `np.squeeze(df.values)` as input. Note that `argrelextrema` still returns a tuple in that case, just a one-element one, so you may need `loc_opt_ind[0]` (`np.where` has similar behaviour).

Comment: Can we use multiple columns in df as a one dimensional to apply for another function ?

Comment: How would multiple columns combine into something one-dimensional?

Comment: I actually want to apply this maxloc function on a list of DataFrames , each dataFrame in the list having multiple columns but I need to apply only on 'value' column

Comment: Then us `df['value']` as input to `argrelextrema`: `argrelextrema(df['value'], np.greater)`.

Comment: I used it as loc_opt_ind =argrelextrema(np.squeeze(dataFrame_list['value'].values), np.greater) But it gives me error                                        
   TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: This is why you should ask your *actual* intended purpose, because now you get related answers that don't address your actual problem.

Comment: Please ask a new question that properly address your problem and intention.

Comment: Don't use both `np.squeeze` *and *`df['value']`: while it doesn't hurt, it doesn't help either: you try to squeeze a one dimensional array, which doesn't really make sense here.